# Save p:inplace with enter key

Tags: primefaces

I have added primefaces inputtext with inplace to have both readonly and edit text by double clicking the ready only text. inplace event is triggering the ajax listener only if i click the tick icon in editor mode.

I used this as reference from primefaces showcase in the link below

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inplace.xhtml

```
<p:inplace id="stackSetDesc" editor="true">
  <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{stackEditBean.updateStackSet()}"                         process="@this" update="@form" />
  <p:inputText value="#{stackEditBean.stackSetDesc}" required="true" label="text">                          
</p:inputText>
</p:inplace>
```

How to trigger the same inplace listener method by invoking enter button after editing the text

Comment: Try using the widget https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/inplace?id=client-side-api

Answer (score 2):

i solved it like that

```
<p:treeNode>
    <p:inplace widgetVar="inplace_#{node.rowKey}" editor="true">
        <p:inputText value="#{category.categoryName}" required="true" label="text" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==27) {PF('inplace_#{node.rowKey}').cancel(); return false;} if(event.keyCode==13) {PF('inplace_#{node.rowKey}').save(); return false;}" />
    </p:inplace>
</p:treeNode>
```

Answer (score 1):

I obtained the deserved action by the following code

```
  <p:inplace id="stackSetDesc" editor="true">
                                    <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{stackEditBean.updateStackSet()}"
                                        process="@this" update="@form"
                                        onstart="PF('loadWidget').show();"
                                        onsuccess="PF('loadWidget').hide();" />
                                    <p:inputText value="#{stackEditBean.stackSetDesc}"
                                        required="true" label="text"
                                        requiredMessage="Description cannot be empty , Please Enter Name"
                                        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { saveStackSetID(); return false; }" />
                                </p:inplace>
                                <p:remoteCommand name="saveStackSetID" update="stackSetDesc"
                                    actionListener="#{stackEditBean.updateStackSet()}"
                                    onstart="PF('loadWidget').show();"
                                    oncomplete="PF('loadWidget').hide();">
    </p:remoteCommand>
```